# Excel nested IF, And, Or

Tags: excel

How do I calculate at nested if/and/or field in excel?

For a “potluck” I need to calculate who is paying what.

Got two variables Kids-Menu Yes/No and Wine-Menu Yes/No. Prices for the Kids-Menu, GrownUp Menu and Wine menu are in separate cells.

How do make the calculation for Total, got the following scenarios:

```
Kids-Menu WineMenu
No        No
No        Yes
Yes       No
Yes       Yes
```

Cheers
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you use IF and AND.

```
=IF(AND(B4="NO",C4="NO"),CALCULATION HERE,IF(AND(B4="NO",C4="YES"),CALCULATION HERE,... And so on until your last condition.
```

hope this gets you started.

Answer (score 1):

To build on `L42's` answer (+1), you don't need to explicitly code the final `Ja | Ja` condition as it must be that combination if all other `IF` tests fail:

```
=IF(AND(B4="Nej",C4="Nej"),'calc1',IF(AND(B4="Nej",C4="Ja"),'calc2',IF(AND(B4="Ja",C4="Nej"),'calc3', 'calc4')))
```

Where:

- `Calc1` = Nej | Nej scenario
- `Calc2` = Nej | Ja scenario
- `Calc3` = Ja  | Nej scenario
- `Calc4` = Ja  | Ja scenario

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for the answers. Calculations in excel that are beyond “Autosum” is a mystery for me, but this gave me some good examples of the syntax.
A guest attending the party came up with this solution:

```
=IF(B4="Yes";Price-Kids-Menu;Price-GrownUp-Menu) + IF(C4="Yes";Price-Wine-Menu;0)
```

Involving naming cells as “variable-names” (prices-cells) – didn’t know that that was possible.